# retrofit change the json value and display

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

I am newbie in android. I want to change this value in string if {"gender": 1} is female and {"gender": 2} is male
here is my code
Thanks in advance

model class

```
public class people{
@SerializedName("gender")
@Expose
private Integer gender;
public Integer getGender() {
    return gender;
}

 public void setGender(Integer gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
       }
    }
```

interface

```
public interface ApiInterface{
   @GET("person/{person_id}")
   Call<People> getPeopleDetails(@Path("person_id") int personId,
                              @Query("api_key") String apikey);
      }
```

response from retrofit

```
 ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<People> call = apiInterface.getPeopleDetails(personId,getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<People>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<People> call, Response<People> response) {

            People peopleResponse = response.body();

            v.biography.setText(peopleResponse.getBiography());
            v.dob.setText(String.valueOf(peopleResponse.getBirthday()));

            v.gender.setText(String.valueOf(peopleResponse.getGender()));

            v.homepage.setText(String.valueOf(peopleResponse.getHomepage()));
            v.imdbid.setText(peopleResponse.getImdbId());
            v.popularity.setText(String.valueOf(peopleResponse.getPopularity()));
            v.place_of_birth.setText(peopleResponse.getPlaceOfBirth());
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185"+peopleResponse.getProfilePath()).resize(150,220).into(v.personImageView);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<People> call, Throwable t) {

            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing new

```
if("1".equals(String.valueOf(peopleResponse.getGender())){  
 v.gender.setText("female"));
} else {  
  v.gender.setText("male"));
}
```

Comment: btw thats not part of retrofit its basic java